# How can I convert CSS BoxShadow to Flutter BoxShadow?

Tags: flutter

I need to convert CSS BoxShadow to Flutter BoxShadow Here is the code:

```
box-shadow: 10px 10px 21px -8px #b6c6d4, -3px -4px 6px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
```

How does this should look on Flutter ?

Comment: look into decoration property of container. it has box shadow list which can combine multiple shadows.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Color(0xFFB6C6D4);,
                spreadRadius: -8,
                blurRadius: 21.0,
                offset: Offset(10, 10),
              ),
              BoxShadow(
                color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 0.5),
                blurRadius: 6,
                offset: Offset(-3, -4),
              )
            ],
...
```